# Fatal error when starting Tomcat mongrel plugin from inside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, plugins, mongrel

I am trying to start Tomcat from within eclipse using the Mongrel plugin. 
Mongrel plugin adds start/stop/restart buttons on the eclipse main window. When I click on the start button I get this error.

I have multiple jdks / jres on the machine. Is this causing the error ?
I think I have configured my environment variables correctly. 
JAVA_HOME, PATH etc.

Error I am getting on the eclipse console window:

```
Jan 6, 2015 1:44:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin;C:/Sun/SDK/jdk/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Sun/SDK/jdk/bin/../jre/bin;C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\client
=============== DEBUG MESSAGE: illegal bytecode sequence - method not verified ================

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION (0xc0000096) at pc=0x026326e1, pid=9276, tid=6124
#
# JRE version: 6.0_21-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b17 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# j  javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.<clinit>()V+-308868101
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\WebDev\tomcat\hs_err_pid9276.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

The contents of the error report file are as shown below:

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0018e000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=6124, stack(0x001f0000,0x00240000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000096

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x00000072, ECX=0x00000008, EDX=0x002d0000
ESP=0x0023edcc, EBP=0x0023ee08, ESI=0x14cc284b, EDI=0x0023ee0c
EIP=0x026326e1, EFLAGS=0x00010216

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0023edcc)
0x0023edcc:   0023ee0c 14cc284b 0023ee08 0023edec
0x0023eddc:   00000072 7ff00000 00000008 00000000
0x0023edec:   026326db 6daf2834 14cc3de0 00000000
0x0023edfc:   14cc1ae0 00000000 0023ee10 0023ee2c
0x0023ee0c:   026302cb 0023ee60 0023ee3c 6d9a3364
0x0023ee1c:   00001fa0 02630266 0018e000 14cc1ae0
0x0023ee2c:   0023eea4 6d9a3abc 0023ee60 0023efb8
0x0023ee3c:   0000000a 14cc1ae0 0263d270 0023ef28 

Instructions: (pc=0x026326e1)
0x026326d1:   68 34 28 af 6d e8 00 00 00 00 60 e8 cf 3a 29 6b
0x026326e1:   f4 66 90 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c0 


Stack: [0x001f0000,0x00240000],  sp=0x0023edcc,  free space=13b0023e774k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
j  javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.<clinit>()V+-308868101
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3abc]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1865b1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3b3d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe331c]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe37cb]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe3aac]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe3bf2]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe39fa]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe3bf2]
V  [jvm.dll+0xeedd3]
j  org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext.<clinit>()V+0
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3abc]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1865b1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3b3d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe331c]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe37cb]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe3aac]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe3bf2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11acb2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x123019]
C  [java.dll+0x13bc]
j  java.lang.Class.forName0(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.Class.forName(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Class;+32
j  org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener.lifecycleEvent(Lorg/apache/catalina/LifecycleEvent;)V+22
j  org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+178
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize()V+31
j  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load()V+333
j  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load([Ljava/lang/String;)V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3abc]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1865b1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3b3d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1a0ebb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1a18d6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11f423]
C  [java.dll+0x7127]
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load([Ljava/lang/String;)V+104
j  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+125
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3abc]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1865b1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3b3d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfd385]
V  [jvm.dll+0x104fdd]
C  [javaw.exe+0x2155]
C  [javaw.exe+0x8614]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x1338a]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x3bf32]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x3bf05]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x01e77000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11008, stack(0x18ef0000,0x18f40000)]
  0x01e73c00 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10620, stack(0x18e60000,0x18eb0000)]
  0x01e60400 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11512, stack(0x18dd0000,0x18e20000)]
  0x01e5ec00 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11088, stack(0x18d40000,0x18d90000)]
  0x01e5a000 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12748, stack(0x18aa0000,0x18af0000)]
  0x01e4e000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13936, stack(0x188d0000,0x18920000)]
  0x01e4b400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13672, stack(0x18840000,0x18890000)]
  0x01e20000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3636, stack(0x187b0000,0x18800000)]
  0x01e1b400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12956, stack(0x18720000,0x18770000)]
=>0x0018e000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=6124, stack(0x001f0000,0x00240000)]

Other Threads:
  0x01e19000 VMThread [stack: 0x18690000,0x186e0000] [id=10372]
  0x18f48800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x19180000,0x191d0000] [id=2520]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4066K [0x04630000, 0x04b80000, 0x09b80000)
  eden space 4416K,  83% used [0x04630000, 0x049c84a0, 0x04a80000)
  from space 512K,  75% used [0x04a80000, 0x04ae06e8, 0x04b00000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x04b00000, 0x04b00000, 0x04b80000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 1704K [0x09b80000, 0x0a630000, 0x14630000)
   the space 10944K,  15% used [0x09b80000, 0x09d2a380, 0x09d2a400, 0x0a630000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 6772K [0x14630000, 0x15230000, 0x18630000)
   the space 12288K,  55% used [0x14630000, 0x14ccd198, 0x14ccd200, 0x15230000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe
0x773a0000 - 0x77520000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x76550000 - 0x76660000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x75f60000 - 0x75fa7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x768c0000 - 0x76960000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x74f80000 - 0x7502c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x75fb0000 - 0x75fc9000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x74cd0000 - 0x74dc0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x74a60000 - 0x74ac0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x74a50000 - 0x74a5c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x761b0000 - 0x762b0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x75d20000 - 0x75db0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x77370000 - 0x7737a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x74ba0000 - 0x74c3d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x74b40000 - 0x74ba0000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x762b0000 - 0x7637c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d8b0000 - 0x6db57000     C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x73ad0000 - 0x73b02000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x73b10000 - 0x73b5c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d860000 - 0x6d86c000     C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3e0000 - 0x6d3ff000     C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d340000 - 0x6d348000     C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x75d10000 - 0x75d15000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d430000 - 0x6d459000     C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin\jdwp.dll
0x6d750000 - 0x6d756000     C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin\npt.dll
0x6d8a0000 - 0x6d8af000     C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x6d2b0000 - 0x6d2b7000     C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin\dt_socket.dll
0x75fd0000 - 0x76005000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x761a0000 - 0x761a6000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x72b60000 - 0x72b70000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x72b50000 - 0x72b60000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x72b30000 - 0x72b42000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x74140000 - 0x7417c000     C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll
0x73570000 - 0x735b4000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x72b20000 - 0x72b28000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x72b10000 - 0x72b1d000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x73f80000 - 0x73f9c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x73f70000 - 0x73f77000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x73c20000 - 0x73c58000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x72db0000 - 0x72db6000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x74130000 - 0x74135000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x6d610000 - 0x6d619000     C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin\management.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:59526 -Dcatalina.home=C:\WebDev\tomcat -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\WebDev\tomcat\endorsed -Dcatalina.base=C:\WebDev\tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\WebDev\tomcat\temp -DECommJVMProperties=C:\WebDev\deployments\FANWebEAR\FANWebWebApp\WEB-INF\appConfig\JVMProps.props -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Xbootclasspath:C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Sun\SDK\lib\javaee.jar 
java_command: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap -config C:\WebDev\tomcat\servers\FAN\conf\server.xml start
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Sun\SDK\jdk
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\EIT\SQLLIB\java\db2java.zip;C:\PROGRA~1\EIT\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\EIT\SQLLIB\java\sqlj.zip;C:\PROGRA~1\EIT\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\EIT\SQLLIB\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\EIT\SQLLIB\java\common.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 5.1.29\mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar
PATH=C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\jre\bin;C:/Sun/SDK/jdk/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Sun/SDK/jdk/bin/../jre/bin;C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\client
USERNAME=dt202173
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 8248860k(2392088k free), swap 16495864k(9130856k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b17) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_21-b07), built on Jul 17 2010 01:10:15 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Tue Jan 06 13:44:42 2015
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this resolved. Putting the answer out here and hope this might help someone.

Basically I had multiple JRE's on my machine and due to a misconfiguration on my side, Tomcat was trying to use files from 2 different JRE's.

To fix it, I went into eclipse Preferences -> Mongrel -> JVM settings. Under the Boot classpath, I put the rt.jar from the jre which tomcat was using to launch.